# what's the difference of setting up a "field" and setting "facet=true" in search_indexes.py in haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack, faceted-search

I'm confused with 'field' and 'facet=true' in search_indexes.py

Setting up a field such as name=CharField(max_length=100) enables me to provide a link with the name that user can drill down to(narrow search result)?

and facet=true gives me the result count for the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Then you could operate on `SearchQuerySet` sqs like

```
sqs = sqs.facet(field_to_facet).facet_count()
```